# AngularJS two directives do same thing(change color), which one changes color?

Tags: angularjs

I saw this question in a hiring interview and I don't know the answer. Can anybody help?

**Question:**

Assuming AngularJS, with simple directives that set the text colour

```
<div blue-if="true" orange-if="true">
Color
</div>
```

What color is applied? And why? And whats a better way to do this?

Comment: depends on directive `priority` preference, or if `priority` option is not mention then `orange` color will get applied..

Comment: http://codepen.io/comakai/pen/jbZJeJ

Answer (score 3):

There is an option for directives `priority` that determines the order in which a directive is applied relative to other directives on the same element or when nested.  The option is numerical and defaults to 0 if not specified, with higher numbers given higher priority.

Check [priority under $compile in the Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).  Also a good blog post [here](http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/) that goes into more detail.

If none of the directives in question have `priority` specified they are applied in **alphabetical** order.  So in this case blue then orange would be applied, leaving the text orange.

Note that the Angular docs (under that $compile section above) state that the order of directives with undefined priority isn't actually set, I've just noticed in practice - as have others - that it appears to be alphabetical.